# How to add a column to array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array:
[image]

Then I used talib to calculate the EMA by `x=talib.EMA(ar[:,[2][0]].astype(np.double), 2)`, I am not sure if this is the right way though, because I need `[0]` after specify all rows of column 2, then I get:

[image]

How can I add it to the last column of orginal array so it looks like this?

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use: `np.concatenate((arr, x[:, None]), axis = 1)`
Check the doc of [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Note that `[:, None]` is used to create an empty new axis for the array `x`.

Answer (score 0):

np.hstack appears to what you look for

```py
>>> a
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
>>> b = np.array([[None, 1.1, 1.2]]).transpose()
>>> b
array([[None],
       [1.1],
       [1.2]], dtype=object)
>>> np.hstack((a,b))
array([[1, 4, None],
       [2, 5, 1.1],
       [3, 6, 1.2]], dtype=object)
```